# Minimap of a notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, gui-construction

I usually code in Atom or Sublime, both of which have a very nice high level outline of the entire file called a minimap. Here's an example:

[image]

It scrolls with you and highlights the area of the file you are viewing. Is there any way to get such a feature within a notebook?

Comment: I'm sure that "There are too many possible answers", but I can't conceive no one. A brief list could be very enlightening.